# tcpdf custom font weird characters

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am trying to use a custom font in my tcpdf file.

```
$pdf->addTTFfont('../../../fonts/RedHatDisplay-Regular.ttf', '', '', 32);
```

addTTFfont does:

```
TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont($fontfile, $fonttype, $enc, $flags, $outpath, $platid, $encid, $addcbbox);
```

This is my Code.
It just gives me weird chars when creating the pdf. The thing is, if I use the RedHatDisplay-Italic.ttf file, it just works perfect. Do you have any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same issue with the Quicksand font. The **issue was the font itself** (or the resource where I got it from).

I tried multiple resources, because in the past I downloaded Google Fonts (like Lato) and they worked.

So for Quicksand the downloaded font from

- https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts *failed*
- https://www.fontmirror.com/quicksand *worked*

**CAUTION** It looks like if the font already exists, it won't be overwritten by TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont so you need to manually **get rid of an existing font first** (probably from previous adding in vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf/fonts) .

Other than that, the following code just works fine:

**Only call this code once to add the font**

```
<?php

$fontnames = [];
$fontnames[] = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('fonts/Quicksand Bold.ttf');
$fontnames[] = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('fonts/Quicksand Regular.ttf');    
// Make sure you use the real font name. Different file names may (or may not) produce different font names.
die(print_r($fontnames, 1));
```

**This code then for generating the pdf**

```
<?php    
$pdf = new TCPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4');

$pdf->SetFont('quicksand'); // This is the fontname from above

$pdf->AddPage();
$txt = '0123456789 ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVQXYZ';

// print a block of text using Write()
$pdf->Write(0, $txt, '', 0, 'C', true, 0, false, false, 0);
    
$pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'I');

exit(1);
```